# Why docker exec command ingore bashrc inside docker container?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, ubuntu

So. I have docker image with ubuntu (also creared container from this image).
On my docker container I see this output:

```
root@61ff2a8dbf2d:/# uname -a
Linux 61ff2a8dbf2d 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On my container on file ~/.bashrc (it is /root/.bashrc) I'm export some variables:

```
export VARIABLE1="value1"
export VARIABLE2="value2"
```

When I try to execute command on docker container using "docker exec" I don't see my variables from .bashrc file

```
root@HUAWEI-MateBook-X:~/Documents/# docker exec -it sly_compilator /bin/bash -c 'export'
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="61ff2a8dbf2d"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
declare -x PWD="/"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
```

Why I don't see my variables? How to fix it?

But if I logging my container this works fine.

```
root@HUAWEI-MateBook-X:~/Documents/# docker exec -it sly_compilator bash
root@61ff2a8dbf2d:/# export
declare -x VARIABLE1="value1"
declare -x VARIABLE2="value2"
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="61ff2a8dbf2d"
declare -x LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
declare -x PWD="/"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
```

Tell me please where I must but by variables export or what must to do to get success result (variables from .bashrc shows when I call try to execute command inline using docker exec)?

Best regards,
Sergei.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` is only sourced if the shell is *interactive*. It's [complicated](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-interactive  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
>          that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
>          exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the
>          shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> ...
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash
>          reads  and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This
>          may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file  option
>          will  force  bash  to  read  and  execute commands from file instead of
>          ~/.bashrc.

In your case, `bash` is started as neither a login shell nor an interactive shell, so none of these files are sourced. When using `docker exec -it`, you do get an interactive shell, hence the difference.

You could put the initialization in `~/.profile` instead, and pass `--login` to make sure it's getting used.

A better solution might be to keep the variables in a file on the *host* system, for example `variables.env`, and pass `--env-file=variables.env` to the `docker run` command used to start your container. That should make sure they are available to every process started inside the container, including other shells and non-shell programs.

Comment: Thank you for help, Thomas =)